# Gitlab OmniAuth multiple gSuite organisations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth

Is this possibile at all?

I have Google Oauth setup. And gitlab login is working fine with domain where I have created API Keys and added Google+ api service. Now I wanted to login with my personal gmail account and I get this error `This client is restricted to users within its organization.` when  and do not know should I research Gitlab or gSuite Oauth service.

Should I just need to add API on my account also?
How should I add anouther google_oauth2  gitlab oauth provider?
Should I read about `hd` parameter?

There is extensive docs to read, and I would not like to bother reading them if at the end it turns out impossibile. = (

I know that new knowledge is always good, but at this time it would be unnecesary to have for me.

Answer (score 1):

This message seems pretty clear to me: `This client is restricted to users within its organization` it seems that "your personal" email is not listed as a register user in your project. I would suggest you to go to:
* GCP console
* go to the project
* Iam & Admin
* Add a new user with your personal email, and make it owner or admin